# Is there a way to change a buttons colour when the button is made in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have made a button within a function and when the button is clicked a command is run to change the button color.
However this does not work as I get an error, but I need to create the button in the function.

It works when the button is defined outside the function and I assume the issue is that the data is forgotten after a function ends.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def ColourChange(Letter):
    NameButton.config(bg = "red")

def Change():
    Letter = "a"
    NameButton=Button(root, text = "This", command = lambda Letter = Letter: 

ColourChange(Letter)

NameButton.pack()

Change()
```

When I click the button I would like the color of the background to change.
The actual error is

> NameButton.config(bg="red") NameError: name 'NameButton' is not defined"

Comment: You can pass the reference of the button to `ColourChange(...)` function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `global variable` so it can be access by other function.Also move `NameButton.pack()` to new line after `NameButton=Button(root,text="This",command=lambda Letter=Letter: ColourChange(Letter))`.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def ColourChange(Letter):
    NameButton.config(bg="red")

def Change():
    global NameButton  # global variable
    Letter="a"
    NameButton=Button(root,text="This",command=lambda Letter=Letter: ColourChange(Letter))
    NameButton.pack()
#NameButton.pack()

Change()
```